# How to remove a WordPress page from a path?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that was made in WordPress and I need to remake it just with HTML and php.

The problem is

I have a page at the url [www.mydomain.com/create](http://www.mydomain.com/create)
I created a new file with same name, [www.mydomain.com/create.php](http://www.mydomain.com/create.php)

Now on the host I removed the extension .php, but the problem is i will still hit the word press page.
Where can I find the file with the url set for this page? I don't know much about word press besides where plugins are.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not use one file per page / post. WordPress instead has a template system inside themes that defines how pages and lists of posts are turned into HTML. The content of those pages and posts resides within the database and can be viewed in wp-admin. Further, WordPress extensions and themes can define hook functions and filters to modify content and style of the page and execute code upon certain events.

You cannot find a file for this "/create/" page. It has some content in the database but the content itself won't render into what you see in the browser.

Sorry to say this, but if you like to recreate the site, you will have to find a new way of constructing and rendering it (and also reusing code). You might also want to look for a proper framework like Laravel and have some proper routing in place (instead of renaming PHP files).

**Edit:**
You can change the permalink for create like so:

```
UPDATE PREFIX_posts SET post_name = 'create_old' WHERE post_name = 'create';
```

You have to adapt the MySQL table name to the WP posts table by replacing `PREFIX` with whatever prefix your WP posts table has.

Comment: Is there no way I can change the url through the database? I can't access the WP cause i don't have the login, and the person who made this using WP does not work here anymore

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try this to get rid of the old /create post.